# Triggered Send with HTML - Escape or replace quotes and line breaks? HTML > 4000 characters

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

We want to send the whole email body via Triggered Send. HTML contains quotes (") and line breaks (return).

Do we have to escape or replace the quotes?
Do we have to remove the line breaks?

The HTML Body will contain more than 4000 characters? A field in a Data Extensions is max 4000. I found out that we have to create an Attribute with prefix "HTML__" in Profile Management but it also does not work, error is

`{
    "id": "f503d4f1-5451-e911-a2ca-1402ec9372a1",
    "messageId": "00780ca6-225c-42df-a602-d9f6af659468",
    "status": "Error",
    "to": {
        "address": "",
        "id": 0,
        "key": ""
    },
    "messageErrors": [
        {
            "messageErrorStatus": "There are required attribute values missing for the subscriber"
        }
    ]
}`

It works with less than 4000 characters.

Comment: create a field in data extension and leave the length blank, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a field in data extension and leaving the length blank, it will work.